# Border and Baseline are not alignment

Tags: html, css

i just start with HTML and CSS

i want to draw a line using Border-left , but there shows the line is shorter than the div box that i had draw (as show on the image )[the line is not touch with baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Qyt.png)

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#topbar{
  background-color:Black;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
}
.indsidbar{
  width: 985px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#logodiv{
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid #E7E8E1;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you also add the HTML for the logo? Having that will make it easier to help answer your question. Just having the CSS only is not complete.

Comment: Give the border-left to div only not to logo , it may fix the resolve your issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use the height property for `#logodiv`. Below are the updated code.

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#topbar{
  background-color:Black;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
}
.indsidbar{
  width: 985px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#logodiv{
  height:40px;
  border-right: 1px solid #E7E8E1;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How am i got ban for asking question ~~~ Dont understand